# Refactor code for removal of if else in reports

Tags: winforms, refactoring

We have inherited a system which generates a lot of reports. There are comboboxes for selecting different options. Once the different options are selected in comboboxes (atleast 5 comboboxes per form), the reports are generated by calling various stored procedures.

```
    if cmbCategory.text = "Category A" and cmbProdType = "Kids" 
    then 
        <code for calling stored proc **SPA** and populating controls on winform> 
    else if cmbCategory.text = "Category A" and cmbProdType = "Mens" 
    then 
        <code for calling stored proc **SPB** and populating controls on winform> 
    else if cmbCategory.text = "Category B" and cmbProdType = "Shoes" 
    then 
        <code for calling stored proc **SPC** and populating controls on winform> 
    else if cmbCategory.text = "Category C" and cmbProdType = "Hosiery" 
    then 
        <code for calling stored proc **SPD** and populating controls on winform> `
```

.... and so on. 
Howw to refactor the code to make it more readable?

Comment: This is a bit difficult to answer without seeing an example of the problem. Perhaps you could expand your question with more details and then flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my code below, do you think it's more readable now?

```
Select Case cmbCategory.Text
    Case "Category A"

        If cmbProdType = "Kids" Then
            '<code for calling stored proc **SPA** and populating controls on winform>
        ElseIf cmbProdType = "Mens" Then
            '<code for calling stored proc **SPB** and populating controls on winform>
        End If

    Case "Category B"


    Case "Category C"

    Case Else

End Select
```